# rx share: avoid duplicate onNext calls for the same subscriber subscribed multiple times

Tags: rx-java, reactive

I need to subscribe multiple times to the same **shared** `Observable`.

As a side effect of subscribing multiple times, my `Subscriber`'s `onNext` gets invoked, also, multiple times (because internally it is added to the `SubscriptionList`'s `LinkedList`  yet again).

Is there a straightforward, built in way to avoid multiple `onNext` calls for the same `Subscriber`?

```
TestScheduler scheduler = Schedulers.test();
TestSubscriber<Long> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
Observable<Long> sharedExec = Observable
        .timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
        .share();


sharedExec.subscribe(subscriber);
sharedExec.subscribe(subscriber);
scheduler.advanceTimeBy(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

subscriber.assertValueCount(1);
// java.lang.AssertionError: Number of onNext events differ; expected: 1, actual: 2 (2 completions)
```

p.s. rxJavaV = '1.1.8'.

Comment: It is not recommanded to reuse an instance of a Subscriber. Could you please explain your use-case, maybe there is another way of doing it. There is no actual way to reuse a susbscriber and only get notified once, because with share you multicast the onNext-message to all subscriber. And if one subscriber is registered twice, it will get notified two times.

Comment: Yeah, I reworked my stream scheme a bit - no need to subscribe the sub multiple times now.